# Is it possible to create alerts for multiple requests from the same IP Address in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have spotted multiple request from the same IP address against my App Service Site, by inspecting the web logs.

Is it possible to set up an alert so when this happens I get an email or SMS etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to config dynamic ip restriction in Azure App, If it is that case you could config it in the web.config file.

The following is demo code. For more information please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/).

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <dynamicIpSecurity enableLoggingOnlyMode="true">
         <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="10" />
         <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="30" 
            requestIntervalInMilliseconds="300" />
      </dynamicIpSecurity>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

> Is it possible to set up an alert so when this happens I get an email or SMS etc?

Yes, you could set the weblog store in the blob and you could sum the requets group by IP, according to the requests number to decide whether send mail or SMS not.

For more information about Azure function timetrigger, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer).